# SQL Lambda adding for loop variable to object

Tags: java, lambda

I'm creating a program that cycles through objects and changes the Team variable based on which iteration of the loop its reached, but get "local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final" error. Can anyone suggest a workaround?

```
 for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
      ObjectList.stream()
          .filter(Student -> Student.getRole().equals("Design"))
           .filter(Student -> Student.getTeam() == 0)
          .forEach(Student -> {
              Student.setTeam(i);
          System.out.println(Student);
          });
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems very wasteful of cpu.
afaict, you are setting a unique and incrementing team id to every design student that has team 0.

To your question, you can always make a copy of 'i' as in:

```
final int teamId = i;
```

then use setTeam(teamId).

A simpler hack (if you really cannot code a for loop and have to use streams...) would be

```
final int[] nextId = new int[]{1};
ObjectList.stream()
        .filter(s -> "Design".equals(s.getRole()) && s.getTeam() == 0)
        .forEach(s -> {
             s.setTeam(nextId[0]++);
             System.out.println(s);
         });
```

Comment: the good old array boxing trick :) it looks a little ugly but is just so useful ! (+1)

Comment: @RannLifshitz, array ref trick is not that popular even for me because it's not volatile-able. I could have used an overkill atomicinteger, but it would have raised more questions...A simple class would do: MutableInteger {volatile int value;}.

Comment: @user2023577 : I've also used volatile and atomic primitives. They are a good tool when having to deal with synchronization with pin point accuracy. Good of you to bring them into the discussion.